# universal NSNumberFormatter in swift

Tags: swift

I have variables

```
var1: Float = 10.58769
var2: Float = 0.2135
```

i am looking for NSNumberFormatter so my variables could look like:

```
10.59
0.21
```

my current NSNumberFormatter is

```
var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 1
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
```

and i use this code to get string

```
formatter.stringFromNumber(var1)
formatter.stringFromNumber(var2)
```

i am a bit confused with results

1) iOS 7 simulator: 10.59 & 0.21 - ok!

2) iOS 8 simulator: 10.58769 & 0.2135 - not ok

3) iOS 8 device with russian localization: 10,58769 & 0,2135 - not ok

Comment: Are you just looking to output these to strings?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking about. Please be more clear what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: sorry - i hadn't complete my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `String(format: "", args...)` construct to achieve the same results:

```
String(format: "%.2f", var1)
String(format: "%.2f", var2)
```

If you're not familiar with C-style printf specifiers, `%` is a conversion specifier, indicating that you're going to insert a variable argument. `f` represents a float value, and `.2` is the precision specifier, indicating that you want to round to 2 decimal places.

Comment: thank you! it is so simple! 
What the difference between style like "%.2f" and NSNumberFormatter?

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that you are missing a property called roundingMode that you need to set to achieve the results you want.

[image]

```
extension Double {
    struct Number {
        static let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    }
    func fractionDigits(min min: Int = 2, max: Int = 2, roundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode = .RoundDown) -> String {
        Number.formatter.minimumFractionDigits = min
        Number.formatter.maximumFractionDigits = max
        Number.formatter.roundingMode = roundingMode
        Number.formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
        return Number.formatter.stringFromNumber(self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

**Testing:**

```
10.58769.fractionDigits()                                       // "10.58"
10.58769.fractionDigits(min: 2, max: 2, roundingMode:.RoundUp)  // "10.59"

0.2135.fractionDigits()                                         // "0.21"
0.2135.fractionDigits(min: 3, max: 3, roundingMode:.RoundUp)    // "0.214"
```